# $\max(S_{n},0)$ also a markov chain$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the random walk $S_{n}$ for $n \geq 1$. Specifically, let $X_{1},X_{2},..$ be Independent with

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=1) = p,~~\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=-1) = 1- p =:q
$$
and $S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$. Now I know that $|S_{n}|$ is a markov chain. But what about $\max(S_{n},0)$? Is this also a markov chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. Keep in mind your chain is now $Y_n:=\max(S_n,0)$, and so you have to rely on values of $Y_{n-1},\cdots,Y_0$ as opposed to knowing exactly what $S_{n-1},\cdots,S_0$ where.

To see this consider the ways in which $\max(S_n,0)=0$. For example imagine that $S_n$ is negative, so $Y_n=0$. You'd need to know the exact value of $S_n$ to infer whether $Y_{n+1}=\max(S_{n+1},0)=\max(S_n+X_{n+1},0)>0$, as you explicitly need to know if $S_n+X_{n+1}>0$. So $P(Y_{n+1}>0|Y_n=0,Y_{n-1},\cdots,Y_0)\neq P(Y_{n+1}>0|Y_{n}=0)$.

Comment: Technically, the more important thing is that knowing, say, $Y_{n-1}$ in addition to $Y_n$ can change the conditional distribution of $Y_{n+1}$. In particular, $P(Y_{n+1}=1 \mid Y_n=0,Y_{n-1}=1) \neq P(Y_{n+1}=1 \mid Y_n=0,Y_{n-1}=0)$. If $Y_n$ were Markov then these would be the same (equal to $p_{01}$).

Comment: This technicality can matter: if $Y_n$ is some horrible jumbling up of the previous values of $X_n$, then in principle it could happen that knowing earlier values of $Y_n$ *wouldn't tell you anything* about future values of $Y_n$ even though knowing earlier values of $X_n$ would tell you something.